# Why EIRP has denominator factor 30 in the formula?

Tags: power, rf, antenna, fcc, field-strength

I am calculating the EIRP using FCC guidelines. I came across the formula in the [FCC guidelines](https://apps.fcc.gov/eas/comments/GetPublishedDocument.html?id=204&tn=255011#) that has a denominator value of 30. That is, EIRP = (E x d)^2/30. Can anyone explain what 30 is and where it is derived from?

Comment: The document gives a foot note 1) which supposedly explains where the "magic numbers" are coming from.

Comment: I glanced over the foot note, NTIA Technical Memorandum TM-10-469, and it was not obvious to me where the 30 factor comes from.

Answer (score 1):

If the EIRP is \$P_t\$, then at a distance d this is spread uniformly (isotropically) over a sphere of radius d, hence the power flux (power per unit area) is

Power per unit area \$=\frac{P_t}{4\pi d^2}\$

If you have measured the electric field at distance d, the power flux is simply the square of the electric field amplitude divided by the impedance of free space:

Power per unit area \$=\frac{E^2}{\eta} = \frac{E^2}{120\pi}\$

Equating these gives

\$P_t = \frac{E^2 d^2}{30}\$